# android contact picker onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, contacts

I want to select a contact using startActivityForResult and then get the result using onActivityResult.

I have followed the example in [Java android how to use contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540514/java-android-how-to-use-contact-picker).

this code correctly calls the Contact picker:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Add button");

            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
        }
    });
```

However the onActivityResult is never called:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onActivityResult");   

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
        {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Selected "+name); 
        }
    }

} // onActivityResult
```

I was wondering whether it might be a problem with my AndroidManifest.xml. I have READ_CONTACTS permission in place; I googled around and added this intent-filter to the activity that starts and waits for the activity but this made no difference either.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="content" android:path="contacts"></data>
 </intent-filter>
```

The behaviour on the phone is that when the button is pressed, the contact list is displayed but when I pick an entry, it never gives control back to my application.

James

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. There was nothing wrong with the code above but it was within a TabActivity. I fixed the issue by switching to Tab Fragments.